# How to connect user securely from customer web site to my web site with laravel passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm stuck with that for too long now, so I require some help. ️

Current stack : Laravel 6 and Laravel passport 9.3

I have 2 websites. Let's say "shop" and "custo1".

A user can access shop with his credentials then do his shopping. This part is ok.

Sometime the same user may come from another web site (custo1) to do the same thing.
The way I imagine this :

- user is on custo1
- user is clicking on a link from custo1 to securely access to shop
- [first time only] user is asked to connect with his credentials
- [first time only] user get the message "custo1 is requesting access to your account" with 2 buttons authorize or cancel
- [first time only] authorize will send access_token and refresh_token to custo1 for this user
- custo1 should get access_token and refresh_token from shop
- custo1 will finally redirect user on shop <== I'm stuck here
- user is connected on shop and can do his shopping

Next time user will click on this custo1 link he will be redirected on shop without being asked to login or give authorization.

I feel I'm close to the solution but it still escapes me. Does Laravel passport allow this kind of workflow ?

Custo1 is a customer web site and I created a client_id/client_secret for this customer.

if you could point me to some good resources, it would be great.

Thanks

here is the routes/web.php for my custo1.

```
Route::get('/', function () use ($shopUrl, $custo1Url, $clientId, $clientSecret) {
    $displayErrorMessage=true;
    $fullQuery='';
    if (isset($clientId) && isset($clientSecret)) {
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'redirect_uri' => $custo1Url.'/auth/callback',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => ''
            ]);
        $displayErrorMessage=false;
        $fullQuery = $shopUrl.'/oauth/authorize?'.$query;
    }

    return view('welcome', compact('fullQuery', 'displayErrorMessage'));
});

Route::get('/auth/callback', function (Request $request) use ($shopUrl, $custo1Url, $clientId, $clientSecret) {
    $response = (new GuzzleHttp\Client)->post($shopUrl.'/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'redirect_uri' => $custo1Url.'/auth/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ]
    ]);
    /** What is the next step to redirect user authenticated on shop */
});
```

On the other side (shop) there is only Laravel passport for now.

Comment: I think this is a bit broad. It might be useful for us (and you) to narrow down your problem as much as possible and share the actual code you are using .

Comment: Added the customer part.